# tSQLt FakeTable fails when user-defined date types are used

Tags: t-sql, tsqlt

I got the following error when I tried to fake a table that uses user-defined data types.

COLLATE clause cannot be used on user-defined data types.{,1}

It looks like it's a known issue in tSQLt.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/tsqlt/AS-Eqy6BjlA

Besides altering table definition, is there a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Chris Francisco, there is now a patch:

> FYI I ran into the same issue and was able to get around it by digging
>   into the tSQLt code a bit.  There's a Function named
>   Private_GetFullTypeName
>
> The last column returned by the function is named "Collation"  which
>   returns an empty string '' if the variable @CollationName is null.  If
>   you add "OR is_user_defined = 1" to the condition for the empty string
>   I've been able to fake tables with user defined data types.
>
> I haven't run into any weird side affects from this alteration but I'm
>   no expert on the inner workings of tSQLt (or on tSQLt in general) so
>   this may break functionality elsewhere.

In other words:

```
          CASE WHEN @CollationName IS NULL OR is_user_defined = 1 THEN ''
               ELSE ' COLLATE ' + @CollationName
```